# Java - Call to start method on thread : how does it route to Runnable interface's run ()?

Tags: java, multithreading

Ok , I know the two standard ways to create a new thread and run it in Java :

1. Implement `Runnable` in a class, define `run()` method, and pass an instance of the class to a new `Thread`. When the `start()` method on the thread instance is called, the run method of the class instance will be invoked.
2. Let the class derive from `Thread`, so it can to override the method `run()` and then when a new instance's `start()` method is called, the call is routed to overridden method.

In both methods, basically a new `Thread` object is created and its start method invoked. However, while in the second method, the mechanism of the call being routed to the user defined `run()` method is very clear, (it's a simple runtime polymorphism in play), I don't understand how the call to `start()` method on the Thread object gets routed to `run()` method of the class implementing `Runnable` interface. Does the `Thread` class have an private field of Type `Runnable` which it checks first, and if it is set then invokes the run method if it set to an object? that would be  a strange mechanism IMO.

How does the call to `start()` on a thread get routed to the run method of the `Runnable` interface implemented by the class whose object is passed as a parameter when constructing the thread?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Thread` keeps a reference to the `Runnable` instance, and calls it in the base implementation of `run`.

You can see this in the source:

```
// passed into the constructor and set in the init() method
private Runnable target;
...
// called from native thread code after start() is called
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably this will often be a reference to `this` as in the 2nd method?

Comment: This does not answer his question. If you derive from Thread, the Runnable reference, called target in the source, is null.

Comment: @Frederik: Yes, but since you overrode `run`, nothing will happen to it.

Comment: Exactly. But I just found you answer easy to misunderstand, because you dont mention this directly. Ohh and just fyi, I did not downvote you.

EDIT: Sorry. I was the one misunderstanding the OP's question!

Comment: Accepted as answer, but looks like this would mean it is based on a very empirical algorithm . If the object happens to be a derived class of Thread, the override will be invoked. else the default , which will check for a reference to be set or not and invoke run() ...am thinking why they did it this way..is this any pattern ?

Answer (score 2):

While you can look at the actual source code, at a guess it would be something like:

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {
 private  Runnable r;
 public MyThread() {
 }
 public MyThread(Runnable r) {
        this.r = r;
 }

 public void start() {
   //magic to launch a new thread
   run(); // the above magic would probably call run(), rather than
          // call it directly here though.
  }
  public void run() {
    if(r != null) 
       r.run();
   }
}
```

In short, if you extend MyThread and override run(), your run() method would be called. If you passed a Runnable instead, the run() method of MyThread would just delegate to the run() method of that Runnable.

Comment: Your guess is completely correct, except that `r` is called `target`, and that the constructor calls an `init` method that sets it.

Answer (score 1):

In both the cases there has to be concrete Thread class. In the first case (implementing a Runnable), makes the class that implements it capable of 'being' a thread. You still have to pass your class as an argument to the constructor of the Thread class. Whereas thats not the scenario in the second case where you extend a Thread Class.

When a start() method is called, there is no guarantee that the run() method will be immediately invoked. Calling a start() method tells that the thread is ready to run. It can go to any of the states thereafter depending on the Thread pooler.

FYI : `class Thread implements Runnable`

Answer (score 1):

You could have just checked the source of `Thread.java` included as part of the JDK:

```
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

where target is:

```
private Runnable target;
```

But I think the real answer you are looking for is the details on how threads really work.  That is unfortunately abstracted away in native libraries.  Just try to get a high level understanding of how threading works.

Answer (score 1):

The one thing that's not yet been explored by the answers is how things get from `start()` to `run()`, which is simultaneously both simple and complex.

In simplistic terms, the `start()` method calls a native method (`start0` in the OpenJDK implementation) which allocates some memory for a new stack and asks the OS to run a thread with that space as stack and with a plain C++ function (`thread_entry` in the OpenJDK implementation) as implementation function. That function in turn does the thunk back into Java to call the `run()` method on the Thread object. The pattern at the low level (asking the OS to start a new thread on a stack and with a function) should be familiar to anyone doing native threads in either POSIX systems or Windows.

The detail makes it all a lot more complex, with all the error handling and obscure edge cases that need to be handled. If you're curious, read the [OpenJDK](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/sandbox/jdk7/hotspot) sources, paying particular attention to `Thread.java`, `JVM_StartThread` in `jvm.cpp` and the `JavaThread` class in `thread.cpp` and `thread.hpp`. Hopefully this answer gives you enough detail for you to find your own way...